# Terminate multi-line string in Python console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

In PyCharm, if I open a Python Console, I can't terminate a multi-line string.

Here's what happens in IDLE for comparison:

```
>>> words = '''one
two
three'''
>>> print(words)
one
two
three
>>>
```

But if I try the same thing in an interactive Python Console from within PyCharm, the console expects more input after I type the final 3 apostrophes. Anyone know why?

```
>>> words = '''one
... two
... three'''
...
```

Comment: did you try just a blank line with nothing in it? (i.e. press enter twice)

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it still didn't terminate. Each time I hit Enter I just get another 3 dots.

Comment: did you termiate open parens/quotes

Comment: If you want to enter mult iline use Ctrl-Enter instead of enter in PyCharm Python console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the context is, but in many cases it would just be easier to make a tuple/list from the things you want printed on different lines and join them with `"\n"`:

```
>>> words = "\n".join(["one", "two", "three"])
```

You may also try three double-quote symbols instead. Maybe PyCharm is confused by what's being delimited. I've always wondered this in Python because strings can be concatenated just by pure juxtaposition. So effectively, `'' 'one\n\two\nthree' ''` ought to take the three different strings, (1) `''` (2) `'one\n\two\nthree'` and (3) `''`, and concatenate them. Since the spaces between them ought not be needed (principle of least astonishment), it's more intuitive to me that the triple-single-(or double)-quote would be interpreted that way. But since the triple version is it's own special character, it doesn't work like that.

In IPython the syntax you give works with no problem. IPython also provides a nice magic command `%cpaste` in which you can paste multi-line expressions or statements, and then delimit the final line with `--`, and upon hitting enter, it executes the pasted block. I prefer IPython (running in a buffer in Emacs) to PyCharm by a lot, but maybe you can see if there's a comparable magic function, or just look up the source for that magic function and write one yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm a Python beginner but I think I understand most of what you've said. I'm aware that there are other ways of doing the same thing (such as joining the elements of an iterable list like you've suggested). I was curious, though, why the interactive console launched from within PyCharm behaved differently compared to IDLE (I thought they essentially launched the same underlying interactive interpreter). I've tested again using double quotation marks like you suggested, and that seems to work fine.

Comment: It could just be that the PyCharm text editor associates quotes with strings slightly differently, leading to a parse error for multi-line strings with single quotes.